# Duplicate directories in $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, environment-variables

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable contains duplicate elements.

It's weird, since I was following the very first tutorials step by step. When we were supposed to check that our variable was pointing to the right places, this is what I get:

/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

What can be happening? I've checked my .bashrc file and it's right (I mean, it just sources the setup.bash file from the just created workspace.) :S

Thank you very much in advance for your time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50572/duplicate-directories-in-$ros_package_path/) by [1morelearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/2840/1morelearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2012-12-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, this is a flaw in the current rosinstall/rosws. It should not impact your work, so you can ignore this. We introduced this in preparation of Groovy.

EDIT: To explain more, the additional path entries come from the setup-file element, which also changes the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

Maybe I'll write a duplicate removal function.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2